# Attaching an image to my email contact form, but image says 'File is empty' C#

Tags: c#, forms, email, attachment

Here is the code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;

public partial class TestAttachSend : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fuImage.HasFile && fuImage.PostedFile.ContentType == System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
        {
            SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage EmailMsg = new MailMessage();

            EmailMsg.To.Add(txtEmail.Text.Trim());
            EmailMsg.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text.Trim());
            EmailMsg.Subject = "Attached Image";
            EmailMsg.Body = "Image is attached!";

            MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream();
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fuImage.PostedFile.InputStream);
            string filename = fuImage.PostedFile.FileName;

            img.Save(imgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            EmailMsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(imgStream, filename, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg));

            emailClient.Send(EmailMsg);

            lblSent.Visible = true;

        }
    }
}
```

This code sort of works. But When you open the attached image in the email it says "File is empty"

can anyone see where i have gone wrong???

Also i would like to use multiple image formats (gif, png). but i'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do

```
imgStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

before passing `imgStream` to the `Attachment` constructor.